# ResignFirstResponder for UITextView in UITableViewCell when scrolled out of screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I have editable custom (nib) loaded reusable `UITableViewCell`s which contain a `UITextView`. The rows are self-sizing. I have a problem that if the user starts editing a `UITextView` and then starts scroll the focus (firstResponder) is still kept, which I assume is a problem since cells of screen are usually allowed to be removed or reused. This causes issues so that the row is still kept in memory and are shown later in the wrong place.

I figure a good solution for this would be to call `resignFirstResponder` for the `UITextView` when the cell is offscreen. However `didEndDisplayingCell` does not seem to be called for this case. I've also tried `prepareForReuse` which does not either gets called.

Any ideas?

```
public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    if (tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.indexOf(indexPath) == nil) {
        if let noteCell = cell as? AgendaNotesTableViewCell {
            noteCell.noteTextView.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

It seems as this works fine for all cells EXCEPT the one which is currently firstResponder. I guess it's kept in memory and therefore never used for calling `didEndDisplayingCell`

Answer (score 0):

Add `UIGestureRecognizer` to the `UITableview` in `viewDidLoad` method,

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer * gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(removeKeyboard)];
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

Hold reference of the `UITextView` using one of its delegate methods

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

When tap on the tableview , gesture recogniser method calls, i.e

```
- (void)removeKeyboard {
 // set resignFirstResponder to textview
  }
```

Comment: This is not what I want. I assume this code hide the keyboard when you touch anywhere on the `UITableView`. I want to hide the keyboard when the cell is scrolled outside of the visible area on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. It works ok, but if someone finds a better one I'll mark that one as correct.

I added a variable in my view controller to keep track of the current indexPath for the firstResponder `UITextView`. Everytime I start editing a `UITextView` I set this variable with this method in my viewController:

```
private var currentFirstResponderIndexPath:NSIndexPath? = nil

public func didSetFirstResponderIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath?)
{
    currentFirstResponderIndexPath = indexPath
}
```

In my custom `UITableViewCell`s:

```
//MARK: - UITextViewDelegate

public func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView)
{
    //....
    agendaViewController?.didSetFirstResponderIndexPath(nil)
}


public func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView)
{
    //...
    agendaViewController?.didSetFirstResponderIndexPath(indexPath)
}
```

where agendaViewController is a weak pointer to the viewController. This can also be a delegate.

I then check when scrolling it the current firstResponder is not visible with:

```
//MARK: - UIScrollViewDelegate

public func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)
{
    updateHelperAlphas()
    if let indexPath = currentFirstResponderIndexPath {
        let visibleCellIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows ?? []
        let indexPathForCellWithFirstResponderIsOutOfScreen = !visibleCellIndexPaths.contains(indexPath)
        if (indexPathForCellWithFirstResponderIsOutOfScreen) {
            self.view.endEditing(true)
        }
    }
}
```

However, this solution does have some disadvantages. If starting to edit a row at the bottom of a tableview, it will show the keyboard and hide the cell which will resign first responder which will hide keyboard et.c. More logic is needed there.